# What should I do with fertile eggs if I don't want chicks?

Tags: birds, cockatiels, eggs

I have a cockatiel and just got her a partner as they told me it's better for her to have another cockatiel next to her if I cannot spend too much time with her. Eventually, they will probably mate and lay eggs, but I don't want more chicks and I don't want to sell them because I feel most people is really irresponsible and won't treat them as they deserve. What should I do with the eggs? Just throw them away inmediatly? If there's no other option, I will sell them but I want to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dispose of the eggs immediately, but the female might lay replacement eggs. That can be unhealthful for the female, since egg-laying drains calcium and can even weaken bones. To prevent her from laying replacements, get some dummy eggs. When you take the real eggs, replace them with dummies. Warm the dummies in your closed palm first and she should accept them.

Thank you for being a responsible cockatiel owner, too. There's an overpopulation problem in many markets, and we don't want to make it worse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you think it's a good idea to boil the eggs and put them back in place?

Comment: @Macarena No! Eggs spoil rather quickly (especially if the're kept warm) and produce a pungent sulfur smell and become a health hazard. Dummy eggs are usually made from gipsum, plastic or ruber. They satisfy the breeding / sitting instinct of birds but don't spoil. Sooner or later your bird will realize that no chicks hatch from the egg and abandon it, just like a wild bird would.

Comment: @Elmy ok, thank you very much for the info, I'll buy some dummy eggs if necessary then :)

Answer (score -1):

> **Option 1 - Sell/exchange the male and get another female**

In my opinion from what you have described this is the best option.

If you definitely do not want chicks then I would sell/exchange the male and get another female cockatile instead. This way you don't have any responsibility over the eggs as they won't be fertile.

> **Option 2 - Freezing the eggs**

If you freeze the eggs for 24hrs it will ensure that they're no longer fertile. You can then warm these up in your hands if your cockatiel is particular about their eggs. I've never tried boiling but I believe this would work in a similar way. Just ensure they aren't too hot when you put them back in.(Including the inside of the egg.)

> **Option 3 - Keeping them together but seperated**

E.g having a large cage with a wire partition down the center so the birds can still communicate/be in each other's company but limits or even eliminates the risk of fertile eggs. I like this one as if the pair do not get on in the future it can also ensure that there is less risk of harm to eachother.

> **Option 4 - Binning the eggs**

Personally, I couldn't go through with this as they are already fertilised and it would have been my fault for putting the pair together. I don't see how this is much better than giving the eggs away if I'm honest... but that could be me battling my own morals.

> **Option 5 - Selling the eggs or giving them away**

I understand your concern with this one but there's always a good chance that they will go to good homes. The best part is as they are your eggs you get to choose where and who they go to.

I may also add it's always better to replace an egg rather than remove it as your cockatiel may keep producing eggs thinking that her clutch is empty. Sometimes adding more fake eggs than what she's laid can trick her into thinking she has a full clutch and stop the egg laying early.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At this moment time, I think it'd be very painful for me to exchange my cockatiel, since despite knowing him recently, I have already created a very special bond with him and for me he's one of the family. I'd keep them in different cages in case they didn't get along, but the idea is to keep them together because that's the advise I got. Regarding disposing of eggs, for me it's not a moral impediment, what worries me is the happiness of my cockatiels, I'm not concerned of a zygote that doesn't feel. And the fourth option is the one I'll consider if there's no other.

Comment: @Macarena - It's not the zygote that's the issue it's the fact that these fertile eggs are effectively your doing for putting a potential mating pair together.
Regardless, for a dummy egg you could always freeze an egg for 24 hours and return it if it's not cracked :)

Comment: I've been told they'd spoil too quickly. I've been researching and I red that chick eggs spoil in 3-5 weeks time, which in my opinion is not "too quickly". But who knows... Maybe cockatiel eggs spoil sooner.So if I wanted to use dummy eggs to fool my cockatiel, I guess I could buy some at the pet shop and that'd be 100% safe.